# Array reduplication not working

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

Xcode problem.   I have a nsmutablearray that is pulling json objects.   Example Company: Name, state, address, phone number, etc.

I am pulling the info just fine. And I want to display 1 of each state in a table view.  It works fine but shows multibles of the same state.  But I only want to show 1 of each state. I am using some code but it does not return any states.  I have seen a lot of examples and this should work but it returns nothing.  If I skip this code below it does show all states.  i have also tried a for loop. And tried array to NSSet.  Nothing is working.  Any Ideas???
My problem is with this code...

```
    //Create states only array...remove duplicate states here
NSArray *statesArray = [companies valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.state"];

return statesArray;
```

Here is my whole code.  Please help been struggling with this for a week.

```
@interface StatesTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *state;

@end

@implementation StatesTableViewController

NSArray *companies;
NSArray *statesArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *address = @"http://www.companiesFeed";
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:address];

    //laod the data on a background queue..
    //if we were connecting to a an online url then we need it
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        companies = [self readCompanies:url];//, statesSet = [self readCompanies:url];

        //now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main ui thread
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

//new code
- (NSArray *)readCompanies:(NSURL *)url {
    //create a nsurlrequest with the given Url
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:
                             NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

    //get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    //now create a nsdictionary from the json data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                   options:0 error:nil];

    //create a new array to hold the comanies
    NSMutableArray *companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //get an array of dictionaries with the key "company"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"companies"];

    //iterate throught the array of dictionaries
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        //create a new company object with information in the dictionary
        Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];

        //add the Company object to the array
        [companies addObject:company ];

    }


    //Create states only array...remove duplicate states here
    NSArray *statesArray = [companies valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.state"];

    return statesArray;
     //return companies;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark -table view controller methods
//change uniqueValue errors to companies

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {    
    //return[companies count];
    return [statesArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"CellIDState";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil){
        //single line on table view
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        // dual line on table view
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]                       initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    //edit single state
    //Company *company = [companies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Company *company = [statesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.textLabel.text = company.company_id;
    cell.textLabel.text = company.state;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",company.companyName];
    //adds cheveron to tableviewl
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

}

@end
```

Comment: what does the companies array structure look like before you try getting the keyPath

Comment: I have tried log but i am not getting any output.  maybe putting it the wrong areas.

Comment: with my filter for only one state i get this..2015-05-13 15:30:04.232 Company listing[3574:100861] array: (
    CA
)  This is correct.  only one CA.  nothing shows on the table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the unique list of states by using a predicate and a block to check a set for existing states. Like so:

```
NSMutableArray *statesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [companies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Company *dict = (Company *)evaluatedObject;
        BOOL seen = [statesArray containsObject:dict];
        if (!seen) {
            [statesArray addObject:dict];
        }
        return !seen;
    }]];
    NSLog(@"unique states:  %@", statesArray);
```

Where the companies array looks like this:

```
{[{
  "company_id": "22",
  "entityformSubmissionID": "22",
  "companyName": "house of waffles",
  "companySlogan": " where your home is!",
  "address1": "123 here",
  "address2": "thre",
  "city": "everywhere",
  "state": "CA",
  "zipCode": "94531",
  "phoneNumber": "777-777-7777",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "additionalCompanyInfo": "all additional company info is going here",
  "sales": "There are no sales!",
  "rentalTerms": "Terms is dont break our stuff jerks!",
  "companyLogo": "/16x16icon.png"
}]
```

Comment: I get a Xcode error..StatesTableViewController.m:81:17: Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *'

Comment: And could it be a problem with the tableview controller?

Comment: with your code 81 is[(NSArray *)companies[@"companies"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject,

Comment: Ok code has no errors now.  But still no results on the table view.

Comment: 2015-05-13 16:46:10.895 Company listing[3978:116117] unique states:  (
    "<Company: 0x7fbba05b2790>",
    "<Company: 0x7fbba05b2850>"
)

Comment: This looks like it returns 2 sets of data.  Should only show 1 set of data.  Why is it showing memory address and not the actual info in the array?

Comment: Well, based on your code you are filling the array with Company objects, so those are the unique objects in the array. Now if you reload the table it should use the Company data in those objects to fill the table. Unless you are expecting different data

Comment: I have figured out.  Everything is going threw correctly.  My thinking on logic is all wrong for what I am trying to do.